Far manager launches program windows in background. How to fix?
in Far Manager, under Windows 11  When I launch a program, file (such as *.pdf or *.docx) or folder, such as  start . it opens in background, with the Far manager being still in foreground, covering the window of the newly launched  program  or file, so I have to look for its icon on the taskbar and click on it to read my PDF or Word file.  How to fix it?  On my old laptop  Far  used to open new windows in foreground, so I could  read my PDFs with one click.
Envirnment: Windows-11, Far 3.0.6364.0 x86
Sumatra PDF with tabs disabled; Word 2016 .
